# HTTP header for decompressed length

Tags: http, http-headers, content-length, content-encoding, http-content-length

When using `Content-Encoding: gzip`, `Content-Length` is the compressed, *post-gzip-encoding* size.

I want to add a header for the uncompressed, *pre-gzip-encoding* size. An embedded application will read this and preallocate a correctly sized buffer for the decoded data up front.

What should this header be? Is there any convention I can follow? Or shall I choose something kinda arbitrary, like `X-Decoded-Content-Length`?