# Is there standardized a way to let user agent know about uncompressed or approximate content length?

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, gzip

I made a simple CORS proxy for some specific giant log files on an internal domain. I need to fetch the files from my web tool, hence the proxying. My web tool is not on the CORS list for the original web server.

Unlike the original source, I also use express `compression` middleware to GZIP the files on the fly. My web server and the log server are geographically close, while the clients are not, so this makes sense.

Since the compression happens while sending the data, after sending the headers, I cannot tell the client how much data there will be. I can make a guess or send the uncompressed size.

This means I can no longer use the original `Content-Length` header that the original source does provide. For now, I just made up my own, called `X-Uncompressed-Size`. This allows my web tool to inform user about the approximate progress of fetching and processing the remote file.

But I was wondering if there was some header that is more universally accepted. Ideally one that will also allow browser to show progress during download.

Is there a way to hint at approximate or original size for downloads that are compressed on the fly?

Comment: to download compressed file browser needs to know compressed size, not original one and it expects it in standard `content-length` header, so if you can compress full file first and then pass it to browser - you can supply compressed length and thus browser will be able to calculate progress correctly

Comment: Previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984567/http-header-for-decompressed-length), but no answers.

Comment: If you can get the _compressed_ size, then you can use that for a progress indicator instead, taking the ratio of the compressed data downloaded so far to the total compressed size. That would look pretty much identical to a progress indicator on the uncompressed data.

Comment: I will put this in the question, since it is probably not obvious, but the compression middleware compresses on the fly, so you can't know the size. And for the files large enough to warant some progress indicator, it is probably better to not compress them to memory before sending them.